# How to deal with "final fields may not have been initialized" issue with multiple static variables?

Tags: java, static, final

In this code, if I add 'final' to the variable definitions, I will receive "the final fields may have not been initialized" error. Some suggested solutions on Statckoverflow tend to be creating static functions to return the value. However, in this case I need to create four different functions to do that. Is there a more elegant solution to this issue?

```
private static String MODEL_PATH;
private static String VECTORS_PATH;
private static String NEG_PATH;
private static String POS_PATH;

static {
    try {
        MODEL_PATH = new ClassPathResource("models/word2vec_model").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
        VECTORS_PATH = new ClassPathResource("models/model.zip").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
        NEG_PATH = new ClassPathResource("models/neg.txt").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
        POS_PATH = new ClassPathResource("models/pos.txt").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, in this case I need to create four different functions to do that.

Since you are doing essentially the same thing, but with different resource names, one method would be sufficient:

```
private static String getResourceByName(string path) {
    try {
        return ClassPathResource(path).getFile().getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you can use the same method four times in your initialization:

```
private static final String MODEL_PATH = getResourceByName("models/word2vec_model");
private static final String VECTORS_PATH = getResourceByName("models/model.zip");
private static final String NEG_PATH = getResourceByName("models/neg.txt");
private static final String POS_PATH = getResourceByName("models/pos.txt");
```